# What is GRAPHDB_CONTEXT_TEST in Graphdb?

Tags: graph, sparql, graphdb

I am trying to set a new repository in GraphDB. The npm documentation say that
 `GRAPHDB_CONTEXT_TEST = 'http://ont.enapso.com/repo';` where is this "http://ont.enapso.com/repo" coming from?

Also, why do we need  `{ prefix: 'entest', iri: 'http://ont.enapso.com/test#' }` ?

In the test repository, it is:
[image]

But I don't understand if the inside the quotes is just a string, or a link?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRAPHDB_CONTEXT_TEST = 'http://ont.enapso.com/repo';
```

This is the global variable in which we have 'http://ont.enapso.com/repo', which is to define which named graph would be used.

```
  { prefix: 'entest', iri: 'http://ont.enapso.com/test#' }
```

These are the prefixes that we could pass in along with their IRI. They are used to perform SPARQL queries which require your prefixes.

We pass the IRI inside the quotes referred to as an internationalized resource identifier. It is used to identify uniquely.

You can also check the updated documentation of the pack available at

[ENAPSO GraphDB Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@innotrade/enapso-graphdb-client)

[ENAPSO GraphDB Admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@innotrade/enapso-graphdb-admin)

Hope that answers your questions.